# Creating an instance of a Binary Search Tree class when using generics?

Tags: java, generics, binary-search-tree

I have the following class :

```
public class BinarySearchTree<Key extends Comparable<? super Key>, E> 
{
private BTNode<Key, E> root;
int nodeCount;

/* Constructor */

public BinarySearchTree()
{
    this.root = null;
    this.nodeCount = 0;
}

...
```

I have no idea how to create an instance of it in my application though...

I have tried :

```
BinarySearchTree myTree = new BinarySearchTree();
```

and also,

```
BinarySearchTree<Integer> myTree = new BinarySearchTree<Integer>();
```

Any ideas are greatly welcomed!

Comment: where is `BTNode` defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `BinarySearchTree` has two type variables in it: one called `Key` for the comparable key, and one called `E` for the type of the node content. You're specifying just one type argument in the variable declaration:

```
BinarySearchTree<Integer, MyType> myTree = new BinarySearchTree<Integer, MyType>();
```

Comment: That is exactly what I am looking for when creating the list! Thanks

One other quick question though - Do you know how I might then call my insert?

it is defined as public void insert(Key key, Element e)

Comment: Something like `myTree.insert(someInteger, myTypeInstance)`.

Comment: Thanks! This helped a lot.